# What are the units of a binomial variable's standard deviation?

Tags: variance, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation, units

I recall that a standard deviation is in the same units as the random variable, which is useful.

However, when deriving the standard deviation of a binomial variable, how do we resolve the units of the standard deviation to be "number of successes"?

The standard deviation of a binomial variable is $\sigma = \sqrt{npq}$ where p and q are unitless and n is number of attempts. So shouldn't the units of $\sigma$ be the square root of "number of successes"?? The very last example of [this link](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Applied_Statistics/Biostatistics_-_Open_Learning_Textbook/Unit_3B%3A_Random_Variables/Binomial_Random_Variables) indicates this is not the case and $\sigma$ is, in fact, in the same units of the binomial random variable.

Comment: This particular formula might be deceiving you. Think about any general formula for the variance for a moment: it will sum probabilities times *squared* values.  Thus, if you consider the variable to have a unit $U,$ then the variance is in units of $U^2,$ whence the SD is in units of $U.$

Comment: I vote for an answer by @whuber :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**One way to see this** is to recall that Binomial distributions often arise from the sum of independent Bernoulli variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n$ having identical distributions (with, say, common probability $p = \Pr(X_i=1).$)

If we conceive of a Bernoulli variable has having a unit of measurement $\bf u$ (such as indicating zero or one of something (usually discrete) things: one person, one electron, one fruit, *etc.*) then the usual formula for the common expectation of each $X_i$ is

$$E(X_i) = \Pr(X_i=0)\times 0[\mathbf {u}]\ +\ \Pr(X_i=1)\times 1[\mathbf u] = p[\mathbf u].$$

I have, as is conventional, indicated the units of all values of $X_i$ in braces.  Consequently the variance is

$$\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \Pr(X_i=0)\times(0[\mathbf u] - p[\mathbf u])^2 + \Pr(X_i=1)\times(1[\mathbf u] - p[\mathbf u])^2 = p(1-p)[\mathbf u^2],$$

evidently in *squared* units. The sum of the $X_i$ is also in units of $\mathbf u$ and the variance of the sum -- equal to the sum of the variances (due to independence) -- must be in units of $\mathbf u^2.$  Taking square roots we see

> The units of a Binomial variable that counts things having units of $\mathbf u$ is $\mathbf u;$ its mean is also in units of $\mathbf u;$ its variance is in squared units $\mathbf u^2;$ and its standard deviation is in units of $\mathbf u.$

Generalizations to other moments will be clear.

If these applications of the units calculus are unfamiliar, you can refresh the concepts at the [Wikipedia article on units of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_of_measurement#Dimensional_homogeneity).